# how to construct truth table for not gate in 3-satisfiability circuit?

Tags: algorithm, logic

Having a lot of trouble understanding this relatively simple concept. So I'm proving that the 3-satisfiability problem is NP-Complete, and part of that involves transforming boolean gates (for example, the NOT gate) into conjunctive normal functions.

So if one gate is a "NOT" gate and takes input a, and returns b = NOT(a), apparently the right answer is that we can enforce the two clauses: a or b, and NOT(a) and NOT(b).

This can be done by a truth table, but I can't seem to figure out how this truth table works. If anyone can explain that would be VERY helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Define a "consistency function" **C** taking 2 arguments **a** and **b**, which is **True(1)** if and only if the values of **a** and **b** are consistent with the definition of a NOT gate.

In your case,

- C(0,0) = 0  (*since **a=0 b=0** is inconsistent with **a=NOT(b)*** )
- C(0,1) = 1
- C(1,0) = 1
- C(1,1) = 0

which is the desired truth table.

Now you can obtain expression for C = a.b + (a').(b') = (a + b).(a' + b')